# How to completely uninstall and reinstall Firefox?

Tags: unity, firefox, re-installation

How can I completely uninstall Firefox, then re-install? My brothers Firefox icon is just blank for some reason on the Unity sidebar. It launches but the icon is completely blank nothing there. If I uninstall this for him and then re-install will it work? Please help. I want to get this fixed for him.

Comment: What version of **Ubuntu**?  11.10 or 11.04

Answer (score 19):

First try moving his profile data out of the way, it may be corrupted. One easy way to do it is to rename the .mozilla directory, on a terminal:

```
mv ~/.mozilla ~/mozilla-backup
```

When you restart Firefox it will rebuild a new profile.

If you want to completely wipe out and reinstall firefox, on the terminal do this:

```
sudo apt-get purge firefox firefox-globalmenu firefox-gnome-support
```

This will remove all traces of the Firefox system files. Then, to reinstall:

```
sudo apt-get install firefox firefox-globalmenu firefox-gnome-support
```

Comment: I don't see a good reason to tell the user the move the profile, since this is most likely a system issue. Additionally, the purge command doesn't do anything else than the remove command when used to remove Firefox, since Firefox doesn't save configuration files in the system directories.

Comment: moving the profile actually resolved my problem with firefox

Comment: E: Unable to locate package firefox-globalmenu
E: Unable to locate package firefox-gnome-support

Answer (score 8):

You can reinstall firefox with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall firefox
```

If that doesn't help, see http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1898600