# Internet is not working in Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04

I've recently downloaded Ubuntu as dual boot on my toshiba satellite C640 along with windows 7. and I have internet broadband connection.
But when I start mozilla firefox in ubuntu.. it's saying "server not found!"

could you please help me out.!! I'm very new to LINUX environment

Thanks..!

Comment: are connecting through wifi or ethernet (direct cable connection to your router)?

Comment: is this with a wired or wireless connection. I presume wireless. Please identify your wireless card.

Comment: Mine is wired one. Cable internet

Comment: First turn router off and on again, and see if it helps. You'd be amazed how often that solves connectivity issues

Comment: Are you behind a proxy meaning do you remember ever setting proxy settings in Windows(somthing like host and port no in LAN settings in Internet options)?

Answer (score 0):

*If your internet connection works well*, my suggestions are just for the "browser" problem.

You can always try other browsers (such as Chromium, etc.), there are a lot of options in Ubuntu Software Center.

If you want to stick with Firefox, here are the [complete troubleshoot](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-and-diagnose-firefox-problems?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Basic%20Troubleshooting).

The short version, each step could help, so try open some pages after each step.

1. Restart your computer
2. Press Ctrl + Shift + Del to clear "recent" history (I know this is a fresh install, it helps sometimes)
3. Open a terminal, and run: `firefox -safe-mode`
4. Reinstall Firefox, following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89638/how-to-completely-uninstall-and-reinstall-firefox)

Comment: If OP gets a "server not found" error. Obviously you can't assume his internet connection works well. Suggesting other browsers is ok in some cases, but completely irrelevant here.

Comment: It happens to me that Firefox gone crazy and other browsers works well so it worth a try.
I just wondered if it's not a "trivial" solution like that.