# Can't search Google in Firefox's Start Page (about:home)

Tags: firefox, search, google

Recently I changed my FF's homepage from Ubuntu start page (about:startpage) to FF start page (about:home).

I can type into the search bar but somehow I can't search (hit Enter or click search button won't do anything): the Google logo is missing. "Restore previous session" also doesn't work. What should I do?

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix it. It seems to have been caused by a corrupted profile.

I found this question helpful:

[How to completely uninstall and reinstall Firefox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89638/how-to-completely-uninstall-and-reinstall-firefox)

I followed the steps, renamed the profile and ran FF again. It's fine now. It's lucky I'm using Sync so nothing was lost :)

Answer (score 0):

There might be some problem with your Firefox installation.
open up Terminal from "search" and type the following :

```
sudo apt-get remove firefox
```

When it finishes uninstalling, install it again

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install firefox
```