# Problem With Cursor

Tags: firefox

I have run into a problem recently where I seem to be able to click outside of a text box on the screen. It's hard to explain, so I included the image below to help demonstrate the problem (see the orange circle, I've managed to click the cursor just below the text box & can't type there). As I was writing this, I wondered if it was Firefox, so I tested to see if this problem was on Midori and it wasn't! So I'm guessing this is a Firefox issue, but I don't know where to start with fixing this. Please can you help?
[image]

Comment: is this on every site or just Ask Ubuntu?

Comment: Every website annoyingly.

Comment: Is there a way to remove firefox and all the settings completely? I have followed this guide, but it doesn't seem to remove everything since when I re-install all my addons and bookmarks are there again http://askubuntu.com/questions/89638/how-to-completely-uninstall-and-reinstall-firefox

Comment: Yeah, remove the Mozilla folder in your home directory.  Might be `.mozilla` or `.config/mozilla` (that's a folder inside a folder), or perhaps `.firefox` but note that if you use thunderbird the first two might cause problems.

Comment: Yep moving the hidden directory to a backup name fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely your Firefox profile is corrupted or causing issues.  In comments, you asked how to 'remove' the profile, so here's how.

Firefox profiles are stored in `/home/$USER/.mozilla/firefox/<profile folder>` on Linux.  You can move the `firefox` folder in there to `firefox.foobar` or some other name in order to make the folder 'not recognized' by default Firefox.  You can then create a new profile by opening Firefox anew after moving that directory or renaming it.