# Firefox stopping

Tags: firefox

Firefox has been stopping unexpected just starting today. Earlier today I got an error: "A web page is slowing down your web browser," and then something like what do you want to do kill/stop wait. Then I restarted my computer and I could barely visit a website before it would close. So I reinstalled Firefox with the command:

```
sudo apt-get purge firefox firefox-globalmenu firefox-gnome-support
```

and it gave me an error: `could not find firefox-gnome-support`, so I did the command again but removed the firefox-gnoe-support part and it seemed to work fine. Then I reinstalled firefox with the:

```
command sudo apt-get install firefox firefox-globalmenu firefox-gnome-support
```

and same error could not find firefox-gnome-support so I removed that part and I worked again. I got these commands from [How to completely uninstall and reinstall Firefox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89638/how-to-completely-uninstall-and-reinstall-firefox).

I did this again but both `uninstall` and `reinstall` from the Ubuntu Software, with no avail. I couldn't do anything with Firefox so I am having to use `Tor` as a search engine since that is the only other thing I have installed and it works. That is how I posted this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one, if you'll go the route of reinstalling, delete the `.mozilla` folder before reinstalling. That's where all of Firefox's data is stored. What I suggest, is checking to see how much load your system is under with and without Firefox running using a system like `HTOP` to determine if your system is swap thrashing and/or if it's Firefox is causing the issue.

As for a specific webpage slowing the system down, it's definitely possible that heavy javascript or rendering tasks on webpages (usually those crammed with ads) could cause severe issues. (Another suggestion is to use Firefox's monitoring tools which will output and log memory, cpu, disk, and gpu usage.)

Comment: or he could just rename the .mozilla folder to .mozillaOLD, that way he eventually could get some of the data like history and bookmarks.

Comment: That would be a wise idea. Backup, as well as something to cross-reference, which might help identify the source of the issue.

Comment: where is the location of the .mozilla

Comment: It's in your home directory. Because it starts with ".", you won't be able to see it unless you enable show hidden files.